# Delphi 7 FileWrite(); динамический массив (Желательно глобальный)

Tags: массивы, файлы, delphi-7, указатели

Пишу код для записи данных с АЦП в бинарный файл,

```
var     //Здесь описана локальная процедура на кнопке
i: WORD;
FullBuf, BinBuf, TxtBuf : array of smallint; //объявим

begin    
SetLength(TxtBuf, 19);   //Кусок массива, который пойдёт в текстовый файл
SetLength(BinBuf, 8);    //Кусок массива, который пойдёт в бинарный файл
SetLength(FullBuf, 32);  //Собственно массив

for i := 1 to 32 do FullBuf[i-1] := 8000; //Для простоты, заполним константами

TxtBuf := Copy(FullBuf, 0, 19);  //Раскидаем массив по
BinBuf := Copy(FullBuf, 20, 8);  //двум массивам поменьше
                                 //Остаток массива пока что не нужен

{ Здесь пишется текстовый файл, и делает он это прекрасно, поэтому данный кусок не важен
SlowFileName:= 'LCARD.slow.'+FormatDateTime('yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm', mydate)+'.dat';
assignfile(SlowFileHandle, SlowFileName);
if (FileExists(SlowFileName)) then Append(SlowFileHandle) else ReWrite(SlowFileHandle);
for i:=1 to 19 do begin Write(SlowFileHandle, (inttostr(TxtBuf[i-1])+#9)); end;
Write(SlowFileHandle, #10);
CloseFile(SlowFilehandle);
}

// А вот здесь в бинарный файл пишутся не значения, а адреса указателя.    
    FileWrite(FastFileHandle,BinBuf, 16); //необходимо записать массив целиком, а не каждый элемент
```

Процессорного времени на итерацию по каждому элементу массива точно не хватит. Пока я использую статические массивы - всё пишется прекрасно, но для статических массивов не работает `Copy();`.

1. Есть-ли какой-то способ записать именно значения, а не адреса?
2. Может быть есть иной способ скопировать часть массива в переменную?
3. Если объявляю и заполняю большой буфер глобально, получаю во всех `Copy();` вот такую неприятность:`[Error] Unit1.pas(56): Incompatible types`
   можно-ли "глобализовать"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать не массив, а его первый элемент: `FileWrite(FastFileHandle, BinBuf[0], 16);`

Но, вообще говоря, крайне не понятно высказывание про недостаток времени для обхода массива. `FileWrite`, фактически, этот обход и делает, пусть и чуть-чуть быстрее.

Comment: Недостаток как недостаток... только эти данные будут писаться 48кГц, а ещё и текстовые, и опрос аппаратуры... Никак не успеет. Указал первый элемент, передался весь массив, спасибо.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. Вы делаете очень много операций по записи в текстовый файл - и при этом не можете найти время для 8 чисел из второго массива? Если на чем и экономить - так это на постоянном переоткрытии текстового файла.

Comment: Кстати, еще одно место для экономии: зачем вообще копировать из одного массива в другой?

Comment: здесь в коде не указано: в программе, для которой это делается, текстовые данные я пишу раз в секунду (каждая 48000я итерация). Кстати об экономии: мой второй вопрос (может быть есть иной способ взять часть общего массива, а не копирование).

Comment: Нет, такого способа нет. Особенно для интервалов длиной в 19 элементов. Лучше копируйте.

Comment: И, кстати, зря вы боитесь не уложиться по времени. Просто сравните порядки величин: 48кГц и 2 ГГц.

Comment: не факт, что программа будет в дальнейшем работать на мощных процессорах. И там-же 400кГц опрос других аппаратур...